# Как сравнить даты в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Я получаю массив с датами с сервера, и мне нужно их сравнить с сегодняшним днем. Если сравнить в сыром виде, то сравниваются только дни. Как правильно сравнить даты?
Пример:

```
16/07/1971,
05/07/1973,
01/03/1975,
20/11/1985,
06/07/1987,
13/11/1992,
15/05/1995,
28/02/1997,
08/01/1999,
09/11/2009,
21/01/2027,
```

Я попытался использовать `new Date`, но выдает ошибку `Invalid Date`

```
import {createStore} from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

const store = createStore({
    state: {
        test: 'test',
        days: [],

    },
    mutations: {
        SET_DAYS: (state, days) => {
            days.forEach(item => {
               state.days = new Date(item);
            });
            console.log(state.days);
        }
    },
    actions: {
        GET_DAYS({
            commit
        }) {
            return axios.get('api/get-days')
                .then((days) => {
                    commit('SET_DAYS', days.data);
                    return days;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return error;
                })
        }
    },
    getters: {
        DAYS(state){
            return state.days;
        }
    }
});

export default store;
```

```
<template>

<div v-for="day in DAYS" :key="day.id">
    <div v-if="day < today">
    {{ today }} больше {{ day }}
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        {{ today }} меньше {{ day }}
    </div>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: "Sidebar",
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'DAYS'
        ]),
    },
    data: () => ({
        days: [],
        today: null,

    }),
    mounted() {
        this.getToday();
        this.GET_DAYS();
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'GET_DAYS'
        ]),

        getToday() {
            let date = new Date();
            let output = date.toLocaleDateString();
            this.today = output;
        }
    },

}
</script>
```

Comment: Для корректно сравнения верните с сервера в формате `YYYY/MM/DD`(пример: 2020/12/01). Пример кода: `'2022/12/01' > '2022/12/02'` - результат - `false`.

Comment: `new Date('01/03/1975'.split('/').reverse().join('-'))`

Comment: @doox911 А как их потом обратно форматировать? Я буду сравнивать с переменной, которая получает сегодняшнюю дату` let date = new Date();             let output = date.toLocaleDateString();,` а тут такой формат, поэтому сервер выводит даты такими

Comment: Вариантов масса, но для начала надо подумать. Или вам надо, чтобы за вас написали весь метод?

Comment: @doox911 Нет, можете дать подсказку?

Comment: А что конкретно подсказать? Вы видели комментарий выше? от @Yaant?